# Multiple screens on debian

Tags: debian, xrandr

I have two screens on my computer, but they all show the same image (i.e I can't activate dual screen).

I saw on some blogs that I need to configure `xrandr` for this, but it fails to do so. Here is the output `xrandr` returns:

```
sam@BARDT071:~$ xrandr
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 640 x 480, current 1600 x 1200, maximum 1600 x 1200
default connected 1600x1200+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1600x1200       0.0* 
   1280x1024       0.0  
   1280x960        0.0  
   1024x768        0.0  
   800x600         0.0  
   640x480         0.0
```

It seems that only one screen is visible to my Debian system, even though I have two screens displaying something. Any pointers would be appreciated!

EDIT: I run xfce4, and going to `Start -> Settings -> Display` shows only one screen.

Comment: Have you tried the standard Gnome monitor configuration GUI?

Comment: @jordanm I run xfce4 but I can give it a try.

Comment: I think XFCE has something similar in the settings manager.

Comment: @jordanm yes, see my edit.

Comment: A brief X log snippet identifying your display hardware would be helpful. Different display cards and drivers have different features.

Comment: What happens if you try and setup xrandr for both displays? `xrandr --output VGA1 --right-of LVDS1`

Comment: Nvidia, ATI or Intel? Which model? Running which driver (proprietary or free)?

Comment: try arandr. it's very simple gui for xrandr. it should be in debian's repo (https://packages.debian.org/sid/arandr)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might want to take a look at this page, titled: [XSF / How to use xrandr](http://pkg-xorg.alioth.debian.org/howto/use-xrandr.html). For starters you could try this command:

```
$ xrandr --output VGA1 --right-of LVDS1
```

You can control the orientation of the monitors with respect to each other using these switches:

- `--right-of`
- `--left-of`
- `--above`
- `--below`

Comment: $ xrandr --output VGA1 --right-of LVDS1 Gves xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
warning: output VGA1 not found; ignoring

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem, and it had nothing to do with xfce or debian, but of problem with radeon driver, I didn't have some firmware, so I did this :

```
dpkg -i firmware-linux-nonfree_0.43_all.deb
```

Find the firmware [here](http://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/firmware/) or [here](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=firmware):