# Set up three (3) monitors in Debian

Tags: debian, xrandr, multi-monitor

I have two identical external monitors, which I have tested in Windows. 
They work perfectly with no extra configuration – just connect them and done. 
When I boot to my **Debian 8 OS** with the three monitors connected,
I can see the mouse moving, but that's all (black screens with mouse moving).

This is my xrandr output with two monitors:

```
$ xrandr 
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 2130, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+1050 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 382mm x 215mm
1920x1080     60.01*+  59.93  
1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
1600x1024     60.17  
1400x1050     59.98  
1280x1024     60.02  
1440x900      59.89  
1280x960      60.00  
1360x768      59.80    59.96  
1152x864      60.00  
1024x768      60.00  
800x600       60.32    56.25  
640x480       59.94  
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 connected 1680x1050+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 459mm x 296mm
1680x1050     59.88*+
1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
1440x900      74.98    59.90  
1280x960      60.00  
1280x800      74.93    59.91  
1152x864      75.00  
1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
1024x768      75.08    70.07    60.00  
832x624       74.55  
800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
720x576       50.00  
720x480       60.00    59.94  
640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94  
720x400       70.08
```

As you might see the VGA port is not connected –
it is the port for my third monitor...

My system is a:

- Acer V3-772G
- Nvidia GT 750M
- Core i7
- Intel Graphics

How can I get three monitors to work?

Comment: Anything here help? http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82352/multiple-screens-on-debian - did you search the site for other people with similar issues?

Comment: Don't give up. It is possible. I use three monitors all the time. I am right now.  Your problem has probably got something to do with the fact that you are using or should be using hybrid graphics. The install of which is pretty system specific. Some laptops don't allow the VGA port to use Nvidia directly while other for you to. I would look around for a guide to setting up "primus" or "bumblebee" and start there.

Comment: I really wanted to get an answer, but it seams impossible...

Answer (score 0):

There is no current support in the NVidia driver to do this without Xinerama which extends your monitor into a continuous single screen. Windows will maximize across all three of the screens and be separated by the physical gaps.

NVidia only supports Twinview currently in Linux which does not allow a third monitor. You can activate one in the NVidia settings but it will never actually start the display.

Using the kernel provided drivers, it could be possible to do this but you would not have hardware rendering.

Comment: I do not think this is correct. I use three monitors all the time in Linux. (doesn't mean I am right though)

Comment: Maybe but you could be using Xinerama, not using hardware rendering, or not using the proprietary NVidia drivers.

Comment: It's possible, but he is stating he has Nvidia and Intel graphics. That *usually* means hybrid graphics, so it's probably just not configured correctly.

Comment: He can only run X through one of those at a time though. X will not run simultaneous sessions for the same user on different video devices.

Comment: Yes it will. That's rather the point of the primus project.  http://pastebin.com/ygLcCb3k It runs some stuff on one X server then multiplexes the stuff on a second X server over the top of it.  Again I don't know that were talking about the same thing, but I have my Intel card driving three monitors and the nvidia card driving 3D apps (on any or all of the three monitors I choose)